# Should this Ghostbusters question be on SciFi stack exchange

Tags: discussion

Should [Does Egon actually collect Spores, Molds, and Fungus?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/96659/does-egon-actually-collect-spores-molds-and-fungus)

be on Sci-Fi/Fantasy StackExchange? Should it be duplicated on there?

Comment: So short answer: no, in this form right now it shouldn't.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I'm not sure if this is a duplicate actually. The OP might be suggesting **deleting the question here and reposting it on SFF**. This would be perfectly possible since it's unanswered here, wouldn't count as cross-posting since it wouldn't reproduce the same question twice, and would be indeed a **perfectly legal and even encouraged thing to do**. (Encouraged in the sense that "if you want your question moved to another site, that's a good way to do it", not meaning he *should* necessarily move it.)

Comment: As the question is currently asked, we don't really know what he has in mind. But these things are also adressed in the linked posts, I think. If not, feel free to edit the question and vote for reopening.